# Using jQuery .html() to point to HTML resource instead of html string

Tags: jquery, html

I have a lot of code that I've previously written using the .html('LOTS OF CODE HERE') method. It is currently formatted as a long, concatenated string, with each line wrapped in " " +

But this is difficult, and ugly, to maintain. Is there a way to save this code as its own separate HTML page and then replace the current HTML string by pointing to the page?

Comment: You can use `$('#element').load('page.html')`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Create an html file with your markup first and then:

```
$('#container').load('path/to/file.html')
```